# Partially select text inside text field

Tags: javascript, html

I want my script to select just a part of the text inside a text field (`<input type="text"`). How can I do this?

Comment: To clarify, you want a way to set the current selection by specifying a start and end index? Or by matching a regex? Or by modifying the existing selection in some predetermined fashion? Or what?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/646611/programmatically-selecting-partial-text-in-an-input-field

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to use Range, and cross-browser compatibility will probably be an issue.

Quirksmode: [Creating a Range object from a Selection object](http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/range_intro.html#link5)

If jQuery is an option, here is a function you can use ([reference](http://programanddesign.com/js/jquery-select-text-range/))...

```
$.fn.selectRange = function(start, end) {
    return this.each(function() {
        if(this.setSelectionRange) {
            this.focus();
            this.setSelectionRange(start, end);
        } else if(this.createTextRange) {
            var range = this.createTextRange();
            range.collapse(true);
            range.moveEnd('character', end);
            range.moveStart('character', start);
            range.select();
        }
    });
};
```

Comment: Why do you need jQuery for that?

Answer (score 0):

Check out [Programmatically selecting partial text in an input field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/646611/programmatically-selecting-partial-text-in-an-input-field) (may be a duplicate...)

Also, a helpful implementation concerning selected text and cursor position can be found here: http://javascript.nwbox.com/cursor_position/

Comment: Yup, it seems that my question is a duplicate. It's weird that I never seem to find an existing Stack Overflow question that solves my problem until I post the duplicate.