# Programatically select portion inside an text input field

Tags: javascript, jquery, select, validation

I have a common `<input type="text" id="foo" />`

I can select all text on click by `$("#foo").select();`

The field does already contain a number (e.g. `25.40`)

How can I select only the `25` part?

Comment: This question is very vague, will the answer always be 25.40? Are you trying to round down numbers so 25.40 becomes 25? Are you wanting only the first two characters of whatever input is in the box? It could mean a lot of answers.

Comment: @thedixon: I think it is pretty clear: Instead of selecting the whole text, only the part before the dot should be selected. Granted, if we knew the reason *why*, then there might be another, simpler solution.

Comment: If this is the case, the answer is below.

Comment: I think Fabio need to provide more detail as @thedixon suggested. it's a input text type, it can be anything user enter

Comment: possible duplicate of [Partially select text inside text field](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2999076/partially-select-text-inside-text-field)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For cross-browser support, you could use my Rangy Inputs jQuery plug-in for this, which will also work on textareas: http://code.google.com/p/rangyinputs/

With it, you can select everything before the decimal point as follows:

```
var $foo = $("#foo");
$foo.focus();
$foo.setSelection(0, $foo.val().indexOf("."));
```

jsFiddle example: http://jsfiddle.net/3XkJE/2/

Comment: FYI: You can add resources to jsfiddle, which makes the JavaScript code area a bit cleaner: http://jsfiddle.net/fkling/3XkJE/3/ :)

Comment: @Felix: Thanks. I did know about that and it does work for this. For some of my other projects, the files in SVN wouldn't work when linked to directly because they have logging calls that are removed by a build script.

Answer (score 1):

```
var split = $("#foo").val().split(".");
var result = split[0];
```

Comment: `$("#foo").select()` will return `$("#foo")`, not the selected text. And anyway, this would never select only part of the text. It is not about *getting* the value, it is about *selecting/marking* the text.

Comment: I went on the original script he posted - I guess he should use val().

Comment: You didn't understand the problem. Read what `.select()` is doing: http://api.jquery.com/select/