# Selecting a specific subsection of a text input box in Javascript/YUI

Tags: javascript, textarea, yui

I'm trying to programmatically select a substring of text inside of an input text box. I found an example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/646611/programmatically-selecting-partial-text-in-an-input-field) but there's only one problem. It doesn't work! I tried it on FF4, the latest build of Chrome and IE. I haven't tried Opera but if it's not working on those 3 it's not a good enough solution.

I also searched on setSelectionRange to see if it's deprecated but I couldn't find anything to lead me to believe that it was.

Here's my code that I'm trying to implement this in:

```
_defShowTimeUnitFn: function(e) {
    if(!this.isValidInput()) {
        var inputNode = this._inputNode,
            input     = inputNode.get(VALUE),
            newText;


        newText = Y.Lang.trim(input) + ' ' + SHOW_TIMEUNIT_DEFAULT;
        inputNode.set(VALUE, newText);

        if (inputNode.setSelectionRange) {
            // Mozilla
            inputNode.setSelectionRange(0, 1);
        } else if (inputNode.createTextRange) {
            // IE
            var range = inputNode.createTextRange();
            range.collapse(true);
            range.moveEnd('character', 1);
            range.moveStart('character', 1);
            range.select();
        } else if (inputNode.selectionStart) {
            inputNode.selectionStart = 0;
            inputNode.selectionEnd = 1;
        }

        inputNode.focus();
    }
},
```

Does anybody know the commands to accomplish

```
textbox.setSelectionRange(start,end);
```

in a modern browser?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`setSelectionRange()` works on all major browsers except IE <= 8. Since `get()` and `set()` are not standard methods of DOM elements, I'm pretty sure `inputNode` is not a reference to an actual `<input>` element. I imagine it's a YUI wrapper object around an `<input>` element. You need to call `setSelectionRange()` on the input itself rather than the YUI wrapper object.

Comment: Great call. It worked perfectly! I used `inputNodeDOM = document.getElementById(inputNode.get('id'));`

Answer (score 0):

You could also get a reference to the raw DOM node using [Y.Node.getDOMNode](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/3/api/Node.html#method_getDOMNode) & then call .setSelectionRange on it.