# How to Select particular text in textbox while textbox receives focus

Tags: javascript, asp.net, vb.net, selection

I am developing one ASP.NET application with VB code.I have one textbox to hold the amount, which contains default value as "0.00". Now the problem is while the textbox gets focus it selects all the text. But i want to select only 0 that is before precision and I do not want to select after precision.

Hope someone will help me. Thanks in advance

Comment: There is no such functionality and no control in ASP.NET. You could create your own `UserControl` which encapsulates the logic. You could for example use two `TextBoxes` side by side or you need to fiddle around with javascript .

Comment: Thanks for your comment.  Please suggest me some other method to do it except javascript.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

assume you have `TextInput` you want to select its first character, whenever its selected

```
<input id="MyText" type="text" value="text" onclick="MyText_click()" />
```

and the script is like this:

```
<script>

    function MyText_click() {

        var input = document.getElementById("MyText");
        createSelection(input, 0, 1); // first character
    };

    function createSelection(field, start, end) {
        if (field.createTextRange) {
            var selRange = field.createTextRange();
            selRange.collapse(true);
            selRange.moveStart('character', start);
            selRange.moveEnd('character', end);
            selRange.select();
            field.focus();
        } else if (field.setSelectionRange) {
            field.focus();
            field.setSelectionRange(start, end);
        } else if (typeof field.selectionStart != 'undefined') {
            field.selectionStart = start;
            field.selectionEnd = end;
            field.focus();
        }
    }

</script>
```

Comment: i just copy the `function` from here [Programmatically selecting partial text in an input field] (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/646611/programmatically-selecting-partial-text-in-an-input-field) which already had commented, and call it from `onclick` handler

Comment: Thanks alot it works. Instead onclick can I use onfocus?? Because I want to select while tab event.

Comment: yes, you can call javascript functions from everywhere you be able to write javascript, if posts are useful to you, vote them, and if they are your answer check them as answer, for other who see your posts

Comment: hi I have another one doubt. For example if I have the following values  5000.00 , 250000.00, 100.00 now i want to select the values before precision. how to calculate the length of digits before precision?

Comment: you can do this, by `regular expression` and `indexOf`... currently i can't get exact answer, sorry

Comment: i am using the following condition in for loop  `if(message.value(i).toString == String.fromCharCode(46))` to find the .(precision) in text value. Is it correct method?

Comment: if you are sure that your value is always from this format (e.g. 234200.00) you can use `indexOf` method which get you the index of character you want. in your case, you can call selection method like this `createSelection(INPUT_ELEMENT, 0, INPUT_ELEMENT.value.indexOf("."))`, but if your value may be invalid format like `200.00.00` (user can enter any value without any validation) you need yo validate your value using `regular expression` before selecting the value

Answer (score 0):

you can do that programmatically using `javascript`, see this: [Programmatically selecting partial text in an input field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/646611/programmatically-selecting-partial-text-in-an-input-field)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. This works in window.onload, I donot want to perform in this way. I want to perform this selection in tab event or mouse click event.

Comment: !!! you can copy and paste the `function` does select, and call it every where you want, attend my next answer

Answer (score 0):

Create event for text focus

Now we have two properties

```
   txt.SelectionStart = intValue
```

and

```
  txt.selectionLength = length;
```

Use this property to resolve your stuff

Comment: Thanks for your reply. SelectStart and SelectionLength is only available in Windows Forms application. My textbox is web control. So these properties are not shown in my intelisence. Is there any other way to solve this problem?