# javascript select only portion of string on input focus

Tags: javascript, input, focus

I have form with lot's of date input fields. I would only like to select firs two characters of date (e.g. day portion of the date only) when focusing on a input field. I have accomplished this with this code:

```
$(".date").focus(function() {
  this.setSelectionRange(0, 2);
});
```

The problem is this only works if I focus on input field with a mouse click. But if moving between input fields with `TABULAR` key on keyboard then the entire text in input field is selected. Can this be controlled via JavaScript as well?

Here is also [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2KQXT/) which demonstrates above.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like the default handler is being run after yours.

Prevent this by stopping the browser's default handler by running:

```
$(".date").focus(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    this.setSelectionRange(0, 2);
});
```

Comment: Haven't thought on this one but unfortunately does not help. It looks like it selects only first tho chars though, but then immediately selects entire string ...

Comment: @PrimozRome I've tested the changes as per http://jsfiddle.net/2KQXT/2/. It seems to work fine in IE11 and Firefox 27 but not in Chrome 32.

Comment: It appears that Chrome does not support `setSelectionRange()`.

Comment: Hmm yes it works on fiddle with Firefox, though not on my project code. Still figuring out what's causing the difference.

Answer (score 0):

i posted here an answer, which is related to what you want , check it out: [how-to-select-particular-text-in-textbox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21604919/how-to-select-particular-text-in-textbox-while-textbox-receives-focus)