# Javascript select text with create range doesn't work in IE

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, selection, html-table

I have a javascript function to select the content of a cell (html table) `onclick="select_cell(this)"`. No surprise, it works fine everywhere except IE. The weird part is that I discovered that if I set a timeout, it works... 100 ms was not enough: it was working half the time. With 200 ms, it's working great!

```
function select_cell(element){

        if (window.getSelection) {
            var range = document.createRange();
            setTimeout(function(){
              range.selectNode(element);
              window.getSelection().addRange(range);
            }, 200);
        }
        else if (document.selection) {
            var range = document.body.createTextRange();
            range.moveToElementText(element);
            range.select();
        }
}
```

The thing is that I don't like this timeout. Someone has an explanation? Or even better, a solution to skip this timeout?

Comment: Does this work for you -> http://jsfiddle.net/WdeTM/372/, and did you place that code after the elements in the DOM.

Comment: Yeah man! It works! Thank you so much! The main problem was if(document.selection). I replaced it by if(document.body.createTextRange) like your example and the problem was fixed!

Answer (score 0):

i posted here an answer for text selection, may be helpful to you, check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21604919/how-to-select-particular-text-in-textbox-while-textbox-receives-focus/21622488#21622488) out