# How do i insert highlighted text in a textarea?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to insert highlighted text in a textarea so when you start typing the highlighted text get deleted.

The same mechanism used by Stackoverflow when inserting code, for example when you press the curly brackets button: [image]

Comment: I think that's for code blocks, or if you simply add ```in this``` with respective langauge tag, that's also for code blocks

Comment: It's an old question, but this seems to cover what you want: [Programmatically selecting partial text in an input field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/646611/programmatically-selecting-partial-text-in-an-input-field). Using that combined with however you are inserting text should do the job.

Comment: yeah @DBS , it helped so this is basically a duplicate.